# Edit content in .txt files with Python

Tags: python

Need a bit of help putting this together

This script reads any files with or with out an .ext 
this can also edit the original file 
I would like to isolate it to a file name 
because it also reads and edits my other scripts 
and it edited itself

```
import os

for root, dirs, files in os.walk('.'):
    for name in files:
        nmin = os.path.join(root,name)
        with open(nmin,"r") as fin:
            data = fin.read()
        data = data.replace('"Houston": ??,",', '"Houston": City",') \
                   .replace('"Place": USA,",', '"Place": County",')
        with open(nmin,"w") as fout:
            fout.write(data)
```

I'm trying different ways and can't get it to work right

```
import os

for root, dirs, files in os.walk('CityPlaces.txt'):
    for name in files:
        nmin = os.path.join(root,name)
        with open(nmin,"r") as fin:
            data = fin.read()
                data["Houston"] = City
                data["Place"] = Country
        with open(nmin,"w") as fout:
            fout.write(data)
```

Also I'm trying to make `data [ ]` work, because every txt file I work on will have different content

```
For example:
"Houston": Random data,
"Houston": Random data,
"Houston": Random data,
```

but all will be update with the same write 
so `replace` will not work

I want to change this

```
data = data.replace('"Houston": ??,",', '"Houston: City",') \
           .replace('"Place": USA,",', '"Place: County",')
```

to this

```
data = fin.read()
         data["Houston"] = City
         data["Place"] = Country
```

Any help would be great

I got help with this part Thank you very much

```
for root, dirs, files in os.walk('.'):
for name in files:
    if name != "CityPlaces.txt": continue
```

How do I add this to my script

```
>>> import re
>>> p = re.compile('ab*')
>>> p
re.compile('ab*')
```

I'm guessing like this

```
import os
import re

    for root, dirs, files in os.walk('CityPlaces.txt'):
        for name in files:
            nmin = os.path.join(root,name)
            with open(nmin,"r") as fin:
                data = fin.read()
                   data = re.compile('Houston*')
                   data = re.compile('Place*')
            with open(nmin,"w") as fout:
                fout.write(data)
```

Comment: @j1-lee - Thank you for the reply I will explain to you and try to update my question - The original script works perfectly, but because of this `for root, dirs, files in os.walk('.'):` it reads everything it finds and edits all the wrong files, including itself, so I am trying to change the script a bit and make it only edit a certain name

Comment: Where are `City` and `Country` supposed to come from?  What is `data["name"]` supposed to mean - `data` is a string, it's only meaningful to index it with an integer.

Comment: the second part is that I am trying to overwrite current content data by using `data[ ]` for example every txt file will have `"Houston": Places, ` or `"Houston": Land,` and I want it to change all found `"Houston": ??,` to `?? to City`, so end results should be like this `"Houston": City,`

Comment: @jasonharper - Thank you for the reply I will update my question better sorry guys

Comment: @jasonharper - I have made my corrections - I use the original script for multiple things and I thought I had added the correct data here - hope this helps

Comment: @j1-lee I have updated my question

Comment: `os.walk()` wants a folder, not a filename. You need an `if`-test in your`for`-loop, something like `if name != "CityPlaces.txt": continue` so that your code only does the substitutions on files that match that name. As for your other question, it looks like you want to operate on the data from the file, which is a string, as if it were a dictionary. You can't do that. Using `replace()`  on the string *will* work. But you have to pass it variables not literals, as in `data.replace(keyword,value)` where your code has previously set `keyword` and `value` to the strings you want to operate on.

Comment: @BoarGules - Thank you for the reply - I added what you gave me, so the `IF` goes on top or underneath the `os.wak` I added a example to my question for you to see

Comment: @BoarGules - Thank you, but for some reason I can't make it work, and I was certain I was able to before

Answer (score 0):

So, you have files called CityPlaces.txt in multiple directories?  Then, just check that your directory contains such a file, and process only that file:

```
import os

for root, dirs, files in os.walk('.'):
    if 'CityPlace.txt' not in files:
        continue
    nmin = os.path.join(root,'CityPlace.txt')
    with open(nmin,"r") as fin:
        data = fin.read()
    data = data.replace('"Houston": ??,",', '"Houston": City",') \
               .replace('"Place": USA,",', '"Place": County",')
    with open(nmin,"w") as fout:
        fout.write(data)
```

Comment: Thank you - I have been trying to isolate the script to filename.txt for a while now, the script is very helpful - I just thought about something I need the `data.replace` to find this `data.replace('"Houston": Random, ', '"Houston": City"')` can I do this `("Houston": [(A-Z)]` so that it can find whatever after the :

Comment: Not with `replace`.  It replaces fixed strings.  You can try using regular expressions for that.

Comment: Thank you, I am looking at this and I found `import re` and not sure where to put `>>> p = re.compile('ab*')` shoudl this go here `data = data.replace(`

Comment: This is veering off.  You need to ask a different question.  The `re` module has its own `replace` method do so what you need.

Comment: ok, thanks, I will ask another question